# store and play microphone data in real time vb.net

Tags: vb.net, naudio

as the title says, i'm trying to store and play microphone data in real time with vb.net 2010 and NAudio library. I got this code in C# from the NAudio Codeplex website and i translated it in vb.net.
There's no error in the code and the program works (i put a counter that keeps increasing and updating a label each time mic data is available to see if it's actually working), but i can't hear anything.

here is the code

```
Imports NAudio
Imports System.IO

'Libraries I'm using
```

Private Sub wi_dataAvailable(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal e As Wave.WaveInEventArgs) Handles wi.DataAvailable
        count += 1      'here is where the counter increases
        Label1.Text = count 'and here the label is updated and it seems to work fine
        play_packet(e.Buffer)
    End Sub

`Private Sub play_packet(ByVal DR() As Byte)
    Dim MS As New MemoryStream(DR)
    Dim frmt As New Wave.WaveFormat
    frmt = Wave.WaveFormat.CreateALawFormat(8000, 1)
    Dim rsws As New Wave.RawSourceWaveStream(MS, frmt)
    Dim pcms As Wave.WaveStream = Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(rsws)


    Dim m_bwp As New Wave.BufferedWaveProvider(New Wave.WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1))
    Dim dec() As Byte = cnssb(pcms)
    m_bwp.AddSamples(dec, 0, dec.Length)


    Dim latency As Integer
    Dim cbi As Wave.WaveCallbackInfo = Wave.WaveCallbackInfo.NewWindow
    Dim out_dev As New Wave.WaveOut(cbi)
    out_dev.DesiredLatency = latency
    out_dev.Init(m_bwp)
    out_dev.Play()

End Sub

Private Function cnssb(ByVal nss As Wave.WaveStream) As Byte()
    Dim memstr As New MemoryStream
    Dim buff(1024) As Byte
    Dim bytes As Integer

    bytes = nss.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)
    While bytes > 0
        memstr.Write(buff, 0, bytes)
        bytes = nss.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)
    End While

    Dim by() As Byte = memstr.ToArray
    Return by
End Function`

hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be creating a new WaveOut and BufferedWaveProvider every time a recorded buffer is received. Instead create one of each, and just add the audio into the BufferedWaveProvider as you receive it.

Comment: i tried to change the latency to 80 and now i can hear the sound, but it is distorted, then i tried to do as you said but the latency has increased a bit and the sound hasn't changed... any idea?

Comment: You will not achieve low latency with WaveIn and WaveOut. The underlying APIs simply aren't for low latency work.

Comment: is not a problem if there's a latency... the problem now is that the sound is very distorted... i tried to set the volume to a lower level and tried to increase the latency, but the sound is still distorted

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I declared a boolean variable and then i edited the play_packet function like this:

```
dim initialized as boolean
'in the form load i set the variable to false
'and then here is the function

Private Sub play_packet(ByVal DR() As Byte)
        Dim MS As New MemoryStream(DR)
        Dim dec() As Byte = MS.ToArray
        m_bwp.AddSamples(dec, 0, dec.Length)
        MS.Close()
        MS.Dispose()
        Dim latency As Integer = 50
        Dim cbi As Wave.WaveCallbackInfo = Wave.WaveCallbackInfo.NewWindow
        Dim out_dev As New Wave.DirectSoundOut
        out_dev.Volume = 1
        If initialized = False Then
            out_dev.Init(m_bwp)
            out_dev.Play()
            initialized = True
        End If
    End Sub
```